# How to resolve Airflow apache-airflow-providers-ssh SSH command timed out

Tags: ssh, airflow, openssh

I recently installed Airflow v2.5.1.  I've setup a SSH connection using apache-airflow-providers-ssh in my DAG.  The SSH_HOOK works because remote server is successfully called.  The problem is Airflow shows the connection times out, therefore, doesnt continue showing logs and errors the airflow job.  I've tried everything under the sun.  Do not know how to resolve.  Airflow shows:

```
[2023-02-27, 23:42:57 CST] {taskinstance.py:1768} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/airflow/providers/ssh/operators/ssh.py", line 171, in execute
    result = self.run_ssh_client_command(ssh_client, self.command, context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/airflow/providers/ssh/operators/ssh.py", line 156, in run_ssh_client_command
    exit_status, agg_stdout, agg_stderr = self.ssh_hook.exec_ssh_client_command(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/airflow/providers/ssh/hooks/ssh.py", line 521, in exec_ssh_client_command
    raise AirflowException("SSH command timed out")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: SSH command timed out
```

This shows at the start of the job (shows connection was successful):

```
[2023-02-27, 23:42:43 CST] {ssh.py:133} INFO - Creating ssh_client
[2023-02-27, 23:42:43 CST] {ssh.py:283} WARNING - No Host Key Verification. This won't protect against Man-In-The-Middle attacks
[2023-02-27, 23:42:43 CST] {transport.py:1871} INFO - Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.9)
[2023-02-27, 23:42:44 CST] {transport.py:1871} INFO - Authentication (password) successful!
```

Answer (score 0):

SSHOperator have both cmd_timeout and conn_timeout set to 10 (seconds) [by default](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-ssh/stable/_api/airflow/providers/ssh/operators/ssh/index.html). Try set both to None in your task.

```
SSHOperator(
    task_id = 'test',
    ssh_conn_id = 'your_conn_id',
    command = "sleep 20",
    conn_timeout = None,
    cmd_timeout = None,
    dag = dag
)
```